# Tablesorter jQuery ZebraStrip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I am following this [link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Examples) to make tablesorter jquery. I've tried to follow that method and it's not returning nicely.

HTML

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>USERNAME</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>NICKNAME</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Hello </td> 
            <td> test@gmail.com </td>
            <td> January </td>
            <td> Hatchiu </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Hello </td> 
            <td> test@gmail.com </td>
            <td> January </td>
            <td> Hatchiu </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Hello </td> 
            <td> test@gmail.com </td>
            <td> January </td>
            <td> Hatchiu </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS..

```
table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left;
}

table.tablesorter thead tr th {
    background-color: #E6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

table.tablesorter tbody td {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:yellow;
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
```

And also I've got `jquery-latest.js` and `jquery.tablesorter.js`.

There are several problem with these.

1. zebra stripping is not working
2. ascending and descending are not working.

and [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e425A/) to check it out.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Fix jsFiddle-link, please.

Comment: Did you link to the plugin and jQuery-library correctly?

Comment: Yes they are linking correctly. I use `jquery-latest.js` and `jquery.tablesorter.js`. Are they useful for this tablesorter? Or I should change jQuery library? @DanielLisik

Comment: Your fiddle is blank....

Comment: @epascarello sorry, I just realised that. I've created another one.

Comment: hey @DanielLisik, may I know how is that works fine? which jquery I should use? I totally dont get it. I'm using `jquery-latest.js` and `jquery.tablesorter.js`. That jquery library in your Jsfiddle is which one?

Comment: @Anthosiast it's hard to know for sure, but one common thing is the order you put the elements. Did you link to the jQuery library *before* you linked to the library and before you called the table-sorting function?

Comment: @Anthosiast the jQuery-library needed is a library of version > 1.2.1, which I'm sure yours is (1.2.1 is really old). The zebra-stripping I can't seem to fix though. Keep updated, I will try some more things.

Comment: @Anthosiast a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z22Un/1/

Comment: Can you tell me send the link to me for download 1.2.1? I'm quite confused. I even changed library version and it still doesn't work at all..

Comment: This link should be working good: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52544/discussion-between-anthosiast-and-daniel-lisik)

Comment: I thought I'd share that I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) that has a lot of bug fixes & tons of features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

**HTML**

```
<!-- your table code -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="LINKTOPLUGIN.js">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th {
    background-color: #E6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color:yellow;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

Comment: The jquery library are still not working again. I think i got `linktoplugin.js` wrongly. Where could I achieve that?

Comment: @Anthosiast maybe you have it in another folder? Then you must define what folder the script is in in the link as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the CSS rules.

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

needs to reference the td

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! That really works!! I won't know that I need to add reference the `TD`.